# What does poll() do with a timeout of 0?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, epoll

I'm looking at the `poll()` [**man page**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), and it tells me the behavior of `poll()` when positive and negative values are passed in for the timeout parameter. It doesn't doesn't tell me what happens if timeout is `0`. **Any ideas?**

Looking at the `epoll_wait()` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html), it tells me that with a timeout value of `0`, it will return right away, even if there are no events available. Is it safe to assume that `poll()` **would behave the same way?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will return immediately:

> If timeout is greater than zero, it specifies a maximum interval (in milliseconds) to wait for any file descriptor to become ready.  If timeout is zero, then `poll()` will return without blocking. If the value of timeout is `-1`, the `poll` blocks indefinitely.

, as of `Mac OS X 10.5`;

> Maximum interval to wait for the poll to complete, in milliseconds.  If this value is 0, `poll()` will return immediately.  If this value is `INFTIM (-1)`, `poll()` will block indefinitely until a condition is found.

, as of `OpenBSD 3.8`

Answer (score 3):

As I see it, waiting for a timeout means "having" a timeout. This way I would expect that poll() actually *checks* the file descriptors, and then waits if no one is ready to a timeout of 0 milliseconds (no wait at all). *But* the case is that it will just signal if a fd is available.

I also checked linux source code and to my knowledge, this is the way it works: first calculates the "future" waiting point, then checks the file descriptors, then if none available, waits for the timeout specified time.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

From the Ubuntu man pages:

> The  timeout  argument  specifies  an
>   upper limit on the time for which
>   poll() will block, in milliseconds. 
>   Specifying a negative value in timeout
>   means an infinite timeout.

Because there is no special case for 0, I would assume that poll() will block for 0 milliseconds.